# How to page refresh after page redirect in Jquerymobile MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-mobile, page-refresh

Hi all i have create a small jquerymoblie mvc3 aplication in that i have a list-view controle when click on the link in the list-view it render to the next page, in that page i have upload some data into database using text-boxes.After updated completed i have redirect to the previous page,Now i again redirect to same page for upload some other data but the text boxes fields are not clear it shows old data how can i clear that data when i page redirect.

I am using jquerymobile mvc3(Razor) application please help me how can i solve this probles..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go back to the "list page" with:

```
$.mobile.changePage("/control/list/", { reloadPage: true });
```

It should reload the page from scratch with AJAX.

There are also several more options for the changePage method which you can find in the docs: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/methods.html